# laravel: error: using join, raw and having in query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I use laravel framework.  I wrote this query but  it shows me an error:

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'schools.grade' in 'field list' (SQL: select `students`.`name`, `students`.`lastname`, students.id, max(`schools.grade`) as `grade` from `students` inner join `schools` on `schools`.`id` = `students`.`id` group by `schools`.`id` having `grade` = 6)
```

my code:

```
$stu = students::join('schools', 'schools.id',"=", 'students.id')
            ->select('students.name','students.lastname',DB::raw('students.id, max(`schools.grade`) as `grade`'))
            ->groupBy('schools.id')
            ->having('grade','=',$grade)
            ->get();
        dd($stu);
```

what's wrong?
thx

Comment: The obvious question: does `schools.grade` exists? Sounds like `grade` belongs to `students`.

Comment: yes absolutely  schools.grade exists in table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stu = students::join('schools as s', 's.id',"=", 'students.id')
            ->select('students.name','students.lastname','students.id, 
               DB::raw(max(`s.grade`) as `grade`')) // make sure grade exist in school? if in student then use students.grade in db:Row
            ->groupBy('s.id')
            ->having('grade','=',$grade)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written like this....

```
   $stu = students::join('schools', 'schools.id',"=", 'students.id')
        ->select('students.name','students.lastname',DB::raw('students.id,max(`schools.grade`) as `grade`'))
        ->groupBy('schools.id')
        ->having('schools.grade','=',$grade)->get();
    dd($stu);
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing is that you verify if you have a column `grade` in your `schools` table because most probably thats the issue here.

If you are sue it does exist then try using the table name in `having` condition as well:

```
$stu = students::join('schools', 'schools.id',"=", 'students.id')
            ->select('students.name','students.lastname',DB::raw('students.id, max(`schools.grade`) as `grade`'))
            ->groupBy('schools.id')
            ->having('schools.grade','=',$grade)
            ->get();
dd($stu);
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked these two queries as a test, both of them separately work. but may main query (I mentioned first) doesn't work.

```
DB::table('schools')
         ->select(DB::raw('id, max(`grade`) as `grade`'))
          ->groupBy('id')
          ->having('grade','=',$grade)
         ->get();
```

and:

```
$stu = students::join('schools', 'schools.id',"=", 'students.id')
         ->select('students.name','students.lastname','students.id','schools.grade')
           ->where('schools.grade','=',$grade)  
           ->get();
```